# Querying a supertable field

Tags: craft3, relations, relatedto, plugin-supertable

I have an entry type called `people` which has a superTable field called `programmeAffiliations`, with three fields, `jobTitle, researchProgramme, primary` where:

- `researchProgramme` is a category field (calling a category called `programmes`)
- `jobTitle` is just a string
- and `primary` is a lightSwitch.

A person can have multiple `programmeAffiliations`.

I've worked out how to get people via their `programmeAffiliation.researchProgramme` category:

```
{% set filterByProgramme = craft.categories
  .group("programmes")
  .slug("some-slug")
 %}

{% set people =  craft.superTable.getRelatedElements({
      relatedTo:
        {
          targetElement: filterByProgramme,
          field: 'programmeAffiliation.researchProgramme'
        }
      ,
      section: 'people',
      criteria: {
        "section": "people",
        "orderBy": 'lastName asc',
        "with": ['portrait', 'programmeAffiliation']
      }
}) %}
```

But I'm struggling to work out how:

1) To get all people who where `primary == 1` on their `programmeAffiliation`

2) To get all people who have no `programmeAffiliation` at all

I can of course loop over the records returned and check, but it feels a bit hacky, and that ideally I really should be able to do this somewhere in the `craft.superTable.getRelatedElements` call. Thoughts?