# How to tell whether a SuperTable column has data or is empty?

Tags: craft3, plugin-supertable, table

I have a "contact table" SuperTable with columns for Name, Phone, Email, and Website. In the template, I'm displaying the data as a table.

I only want to generate table columns if a column has data. For example, if there are no Phone Numbers included, I don't want a Phone column. If even one row has a phone number, I do want to include that column.

How do I create a conditional to check whether a SuperTable column has data in it?

This might be related to [Querying a supertable field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30373/querying-a-supertable-field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget who solved this for me! I think it was Michael van Dorth.

```
<div class="table-overflow content-row">
    <table class="table {{ table_class }}">

      {# Caption #}
      {% if block.caption %}
        <caption class="caption">{{ block.caption }}</caption>
      {% endif %}

      {# Setup #}
      {% set rows = block.contactTable.all() %}
      {% set phoneRows = 0 %}
      {% set emailRows = 0 %}
      {% set websiteRows = 0 %}

      {% for row in rows %}
        {% if row.phone != '' %}
          {% set phoneRows = phoneRows + 1 %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if row.email != '' %}
          {% set emailRows = emailRows + 1 %}
        {% endif %}
        {% if row.website != '' %}
          {% set websiteRows = websiteRows + 1 %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {# Headings #}
      <thead class="thead_class">
        <tr>
          <th scope="col">Name</th>
          {% if phoneRows > 0 %}<th scope="col">Phone</th>{% endif %}
          {% if emailRows > 0 %}<th scope="col">Email</th>{% endif %}
          {% if websiteRows > 0 %}<th scope="col">Website</th>{% endif %}
        </tr>
      </thead>

      {# Body #}
      <tbody class="tbody_class">
        {% for row in block.contactTable.all() %}

          <tr>

            <th scope="row">{{ row.contactName }}</th>

            {% if phoneRows > 0 %}
              <td>{% if row.phone|length %}{{ row.phone.link }}{% endif %}</td>
            {% endif %}

            {% if emailRows > 0 %}
              <td>{% if row.email|length %}
                <a class="btn" href="{{ row.email.url }}" aria-label="{{ row.contactName ~ ' email' }}">Email</a>
              {% endif %}</td>
            {% endif %}

            {% if websiteRows > 0 %}
              <td>{% if row.website|length %}
                <a class="btn" href="{{ row.website.url }}" aria-label="{{ row.contactName ~ ' website' }}">Website</a>
              {% endif %}</td>
            {% endif %}

          </tr>

        {% endfor %}
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>
```